# Repeating elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm sure this is going to be obvious to the right person, but how can I repeat an element with jQuery? Esentially I want jQuery to repeat an inline element an infinite number of times; like you would use CSS to repeat a graphic for a background texture. I've been researching .clone() and .each() but but could really use some pointers.

Thanks!

- J

Comment: What practical purpose could you have for repeating elements an infinite number of times?

Comment: Hmmm... Only idea I have is for spamming background with invisible text for spam robots, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @bozdoz I have this concept for a page of repeated elements with simple CSS animations being triggered when you hover over them. Guess infinite was the wrong word to use...more like fill a page.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/gRTTJ/

Key line:

```
$("#repeating").append($(".foobar").clone());
```

Although if you want it infinitely, it will be an infinite loop (obviously) and not be too useful.

A slightly more reasonable version that runs infinitely:

```
function repeat()
{

   $("#repeating").append($(".foobar:first").clone());
}

$(function () {

    setInterval(repeat, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Your code will repeat only one time. In repeat should be also `setInterval(repeat, 1000);` or you should use [jQuery.doTimeout](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/docs/files/jquery-ba-dotimeout-js.html)

Comment: You're confusing setInterval with setTimeout.  setInterval runs continuously.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Late hour for me so I'm a little bit tired.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(true) {
  $('#infinity-repeat').append('some text');
}
```

But that code will crash your browser. Better idea is to do it countable times.

Comment: @purmou are you sure that's true?  I think he's just appending text to a single ID.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/fNnKd/2/)'s what I came up with:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var length = $(".hi").length;
    if(length >= 10){
        // don't append
    } else {
        $("<div class='hi'>text</div>").appendTo("body");
    }
}, 1);
```

A couple things are happening here. First (besides`setInterval()`), we're getting the length of elements with class `hi`. Of course, at first it will be 0. Then we're checking if it's greater than or equal to 10. If it is, we're not appending it. Otherwise, we continue appending.

This goes on until there are 10 elements with the class `hi` on the page. Of course, I just limited it to give you a glimpse at how it works. If you just continued appending with `setInterval()` it would look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/fNnKd/3/) (and this one doesn't crash your browser).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you want to clone something `finitely` but that aside here is an example of a plugin type of duplication / clone:

Given this html:

```
<div id='duplicateme'>Duplicate This</div>
```

And the plugin itself:

```
$.fn.duplicate = function(count, withDataAndEvents) {
    var tmp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        $.merge(tmp, this.clone(withDataAndEvents).get());
    }
    return this.pushStack(tmp);
};
```

Can be called in two ways:

```
// duplicate item 5 times
$('#duplicateme').duplicate(5).appendTo('#duplicateme');

// duplicate item 5 times along with attached events
$('#duplicateme').duplicate(5, true).appendTo('#duplicateme')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastAppended = $("<span>some text</span>");
var repeatingArea = $("#repeating");
repeatingArea.append(lastAppended);
while (lastAppended.position().top < repeatingArea.height()) {
    lastAppended = lastAppended.clone();
    repeatingArea.append(lastAppended);
}
```

That should fill the repeating area. If the repeating area can have scroll-bars, then the test in the while loop gets a bit more complicated, and you'll need to re-call this whenever the user scrolls, but the idea is the same.

EDIT: here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6FW4n/3/
note that if the height isn't set, it'll be an infinite loop