# How to repeat html code within html to make the html code more concise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an html list that exists several times within my html code and the issue is that when I make a change to one of the lists, I have to change the other lists to keep them identical.

Is there anyway to write the list only once and have it repeat where ever I need it in the rest of the code?

I'm trying to find ways to do this, and came across this question, which suggests using javascript or using a templating library, which I'm having difficulty implementing.

([codepen here](http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/rrZkyB?editors=1100))

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
```

```
<span class="btn-group">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Drop Down List</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Row 1</li>
    <li>Row 2</li>
    <li>Row 3</li>
    <li>Row 4</li>
    <li>Row 5</li>
  </ul>
</span>

<br>

<span class="btn-group">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Drop Down List</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Row 1</li>
    <li>Row 2</li>
    <li>Row 3</li>
    <li>Row 4</li>
    <li>Row 5</li>
  </ul>
</span>
<br>

<span class="btn-group">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Drop Down List</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Row 1</li>
    <li>Row 2</li>
    <li>Row 3</li>
    <li>Row 4</li>
    <li>Row 5</li>
  </ul>
</span>
<br>

<span class="btn-group">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Drop Down List</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Row 1</li>
    <li>Row 2</li>
    <li>Row 3</li>
    <li>Row 4</li>
    <li>Row 5</li>
  </ul>
</span>

<br>

<span class="btn-group">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Drop Down List</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Row 1</li>
    <li>Row 2</li>
    <li>Row 3</li>
    <li>Row 4</li>
    <li>Row 5</li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

Essentially I'd like to deliver the same outcome as the above code, but only have to write the list once.

Comment: It sounds like the easiest way would be to remove the originals and append some `clone()` of the new version. A more complete example of your code would help though, so we can see what event you're running under and exactly how the elements change

Comment: angular provide ng-repeat which you can use

Comment: You could keep a template of your list in a hidden DIV and whenever you need a list, you [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) the template. Take care if elements in your template list have ID attributes - make sure the clones have unique IDs then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249473/repeating-elements-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of the hip frameworks like Angular, React or Vue - which all provide nice solutions for this use case - are total overkill for your project, with jQuery you can do something like that:

```
$(".dropdown-menu").each(function(){
    var list = "";
    for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++){
        list += "<li>Custom Row " + i + "</li>";
    }
    $(this).html(list);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/27hh9sh2/

This answer assumes you want to change those lists on the fly, meaning in the client. If you serve a static html page, where your navigation links change like once a month, you want to use server side templating.

Answer (score 0):

If your server has server side includes, you could rename your file from `.html` to `.shtml`, copy the repeating bits in a separate file and use include to put that code wherever you need
`<!--#include file="repeating_code.txt"-->`
Naturally, the above assumes that the file "repeating_code.txt" is in the same directory as the `.shtml` where it's going to be inserted.